# Responsive mobile design

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, responsive-design

I developed a website. The layout is fine in desktop. But it is not responsive. I tried for mobile with media queries like,

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px)
{
.....
}
```

I am using chrome development tools and make changes in the site according to the size 320 x 640. Now the problem is fine in simulator but not in the actual mobile.

Help me to find the solution.

Comment: Have you tried `twitter-bootstrap` framework? It does all this tasks for you..

Comment: Have you added this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> in the html header part?

Comment: No.I don't have knowledge about bootstrap.

Comment: Yes.. I added..@Sujith

Comment: I wouldn't over-complicate things with height if you don't _need_ too. `@media(max-width: 500px){ /*styles here*/ }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries Also, check this out if you're doing media queries, there's a difference between scaling up & down that is good to know: https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-mobile-first-media-queries/ , https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

Comment: Can you try to change the max-device-width to just max-width and apply the same to min-device-width as well. Might not work always.. but some devices may not properly report device-width. Reasoning can be found here : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/#css-media-queries

Comment: For debugging sake, you can connect your device to desktop through USB and do some "remote debugging" in chrome browser, with which you can see if the CSS is being applied or not in the dev tools.

Comment: One more pointer: Just remove max-device-width at first and see if at least the min-device-width is giving the effect you desired - For some testing

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you describe suggest that you may not have a viewport metatag in the head of your page, so double check this first.

What you want is something like

```
<head>  
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
...  
</head>
```

More about viewport meta tags
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag